# LateXML can't find binding for class

Tags: pdftex, texlive, dvi, binding, latexml

I'm using LateXml for the first time and I can't get the conversion.

There are some details I must comment first:

1. I use TexLive 2019 in linux.
2. I'm using a .cls file in which the documentclass is defined. This is a customized one.
3. To compile the latex files I use pdflatex and I get a .pdf file but not a .dvi one.
4. On LateXML I type the following command

   latexml --includestyles --destination=../myDirectory/myfile.xml myfile.tex

When I compile I get this warning first:

```
Warning:missing_file:MYCLASSFILE Can't find binding for class MYCLASS (using OmniBus)
    at /home/...../file.tex; line 8 col 11
    Anticipate undefined macros or environments
```

After this a plenty of errors follows, like:

```
The token ... is not defined
```

The last error is a fatal one:

```
Fatal:misdefined:LaTeXML::Package::Pool::__ANON__ Can't locate method 'isRegister' via 'missing'
```

I don't know what exactly is a binding in LateXml's jargon but, by reading some sites, I begin to think that it could be necessary to write a customized binding for a customized class file. Is this true? Is there any other option?

I wouldn't like to have to write a binding because I have not much experience using neither TeX nor Perl.
But I will really appreciate any help or hint.

Comment: If the documentclass is based on one of the supported classes (which is often the case, look for a `\LoadClass` statement in the `.cls` file) then you could try providing the binding to this base class to LaTeXML using the `--preload` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, latexml will need help to interpret a custom `.cls` file that it doesn't have a `.cls.ltxml` binding for yet. On the hopeful side, some of our bindings are quite small, especially in cases where the custom class file is derived from a supported standard one, and has just a few changed macros.

You would need to do some extra rearrangements to make your document work without entering the land of Perl, ideally switching over to a supported class and copying over any definitions you'd like interpreted directly. While we would like to be able to natively interpret any custom `.cls` file, that is not something latexml is automatically capable of yet.